# How do i put the file name in the url?

Tags: javascript, express

i have `dog_001.jpg` in `image/animal/` directory then i want to put the `dog_001.jpg`to `https://api.example.com/dog/`

example: `https://api.example.com/dog/` and it will respond `https://api.example.com/img/animal/dog_001.jpg` i already made it respond with `https://api.example.com/img/animal/dog_001.jpg` this but it says Cannot get /img/animal/dog_001

here is my current code

my index.js file

```js
global.config = require("./config.json");

const express = require('express');
const helmet = require("helmet");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

//Animal API app
const animalapp = express();
const animalserver = require('http').createServer(animalapp);
const APIPORT = config.APIPort;
const apihbs = require('hbs');

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
global.fs = require("fs");
global.chalk = require('chalk');
const axios = require('axios');


//Animal API website
animalapp.use(helmet({
    frameguard: false
}));
animalapp.use(cookieParser());

animalapp.use(bodyParser.json());
animalapp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

animalserver.listen(APIPORT, function () {
    console.log(chalk.magenta('[api.example.com] [WEB] ') + chalk.green("Listening on port " + APIPORT));
});

const dogRoute = require("./api/reaction/dog.js");
animalapp.use("/img/sfw/dog/gif", dogRoute);
```

my dog.js (./api/reaction/dog.js)

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Router = require("express").Router();

Router.get("/", (req, res) => {

    var files = fs.readdirSync('./src/animal/dog')
    let imagenumber = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]
    let data = {
        image: "https://example.com/img/animal/dog/" + imagenumber,
        success: true,
        status: 200
    };

    res.json(data);
});

Router.get('*', (req, res) => {
    if (fs.existsSync('./src/animal/dog/' + req.path)) {
        var img = fs.readFileSync('./src/animal/dog/' + req.path);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif'});
        res.end(img, 'binary')
    } else {
        res.send('404')
    }
})

module.exports = Router;
```

Comment: Can you share a repo link for the project?

Comment: It says `Cannot get /img/animal/dog_001` instead of `Cannot get /img/animal/dog_001.jpg`? so it is missing the file ending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi KASKUSTTV and welcome to Stack Overflow,

I guess you want to have the person see the image at your route, right?

The best way is then using `res.sendFile` and send the file directly on the route, making sure that the `MIME` type is set correctly, this way the browser will just open the image on the window.

Try not reading in from the disk, but just send it as a file.

Btw never use `sync` methods on request handlers as those block the loop and the whole server is stuck until those are over. `Node` provides async methods for all of those operations.